# My IFS MATCH Formula wont return correct

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use sheets to help calculate a players level based on xp, there are 2 things that effect how much xp is needed to level up, one is a reduction of xp needed by 5% and the other increases the xp needed by either 5% or 10%. This means there are 6 different boundaries for each level (base, base-5%, base+5%, base+10%, (base+5%)-5%, (base+10%)-5%). I have a separate sheet with a table of levels and the 6 boundaries(column A = level, column B = base xp, column C = base+5%, etc)
In the main sheet d1 works out a number, 0 to 5,  based on if they have anything effecting level boundaries. B1 is the players current xp. Then I have this code to work out the level

```
=IFS(D1=0,match(B1, XP!B1:B100),D1=1,match(B1,XP!C1:C100),D1=2,match(B1,XP!D1:D100),D1=3,match(B1,XP!E1:E100),D1=4,match(B1,XP!F1:F100),D1=5,match(B1,XP!G1:G100))
```

If d1=0 the formula works and I get the correct level, of d1=anything but 0 it just out puts the highest level in the table.

Am I using the right formula here is  there a better way to do this? If the method is right what have I done wrong?

Sorry if long winded first time posting and thought would get as much detail as possible for your guys help.

Thanks in advance

**edit** heres a link to the file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gn6qla9Vo9-XgkURfyVftYjCLu3IoFQHC_JjH1kV3C0/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I suggest you attach the link to your file, so that helping you will be easier

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, have added the link

Comment: well, but now unlock his access :)

Comment: Sorry, that's done now

Comment: You have to clear all those zeros from the XP sheet, otherwise match () doesn't work because the values ​​are not sorted.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is to make all those zeros disappear from the `XP!` sheet, otherwise `match()` doesn't work because the values ​​are not sorted.
For example, change the formula of column `XP!B` to

```
=index(if(B1:B,B1:B*1.05,))
```

[here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CdvKOAwxeysGJIMs6j183W4hYLfn8WIPcqT1KhUyMcs/edit?usp=sharing) your sheet modified